# .htaccess remove square brackets from URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I had many URLs with square brackets. Then I changed these URLs and removed all square brackets from them, but I still get soft 404 errors, because old URLs are indexed in the web. The URLs are vary, I can redirect each URLs manually, but It will be better if I'll use some universal rule in .htaccess, which removes all square brackets from the URLs.

```
http://www.example.com/page-[first]
http://www.example.com/page-[second]
```

etc.. will replaced with:

```
http://www.example.com/page-first
http://www.example.com/page-second
```

Can I do it with .htaccess?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\[(.*)$ $1$2 [N,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\](.*)$ $1$2 [N,R=301]
```

If your .htacess is in a sub folder, change `RewriteBase /` with:

```
RewriteBase /sub-folder-name
```

Here's my `access_log` - which shows the redirections:

```
::1 - - [04/Jun/2016:12:29:23 +0800] "GET /test/hello-[world].html HTTP/1.1" 301 246
::1 - - [04/Jun/2016:12:29:23 +0800] "GET /test/hello-world.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3
::1 - - [04/Jun/2016:12:37:45 +0800] "GET /test/hello-%5bworld%5d.html HTTP/1.1" 301 246
::1 - - [04/Jun/2016:12:37:45 +0800] "GET /test/hello-world.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: Thank you James for your quick response. I tried it but brackets converted with %5b and %5d.

Comment: On my end, even if the URL is test-[page].html, or test-%5bpage%5d.html, redirection works well. Is your .htaccess in a sub folder?

Comment: No, it's in the main/root folder

Comment: Add this below `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteBase /` (see edited answer above)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this redirection using a single rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page-(?:%5B|\[)(.*?)(?:%5D|\]) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
```